# Creating objects based on the year and month fields

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects `entries`, where the objects have `year` and `month` as keys. I would like to restructure the array such that entries of the same year are grouped together at the top level, and the entries of the same month of the same year are grouped together in an array. Something like this

```
{
 2020:{
      "January": [objJan1, ObjJan2, ...],
      "June": [objJune1, ObjJune2, ...],
 },
 2019:{
      "April": [objApril1, ObjApril2, ...],
      "July": [objJul1, ObjJul2, ...],
 },
...
}
```

I tried this

```
let entriesByYearMonth = {};
  entries.forEach((entryEl) => {
    const entryElYear = entryEl.year.toString();
    const entryElMonth = entryEl.month.toString();
    console.log(Object.keys(entriesByYearMonth), typeof entryElYear);
    if (entryElYear in Object.keys(entriesByYearMonth)) {
      let entriesByYear = entriesByYearMonth[entryElYear];
      if (entryElMonth in Object.keys(entriesByYear)) {
        entriesByYear[entryElMonth] = [];
      } else {
        entriesByYear[entryElMonth].push(entryEl);
      }
    } else {
      entriesByYearMonth[entryElYear] = { [entryElMonth]: [entryEl] };
    }
  });
```

but the code doesn't enter the if statement `if (entryElYear in Object.keys(entriesByYearMonth))`  for the next entry with the same year, although `entryElYear` is of type string, and `Object.keys(entriesByYearMonth)` is an array of strings. I am not sure why? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The structure of `entries`

```
[
 {
  key1: ...,
  ..
  year: 2020,
  month: "December",
  ...
 },
 {
  key11: ...,
  ..
  year: 2020,
  month: "December",
  ...
 },
{
  key12: ...,
  ..
  year: 2019,
  month: "January",
  ...
 },
...
]
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of entries?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

By reducer you can group by year, like this:

```
const entriesByYearMonth = entries.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
    accumulator[item.year] = accumulator[item.year] || {};
    accumulator[item.year][item.month] = accumulator[item.year][item.month] || [];  
    accumulator[item.year][item.month].push(item);
    return accumulator;
},{});
```

Comment: This gives `{item: ..}` with the `item` as the key. I want the key to be the year. Also, it doesn't group the items of the same year. the key `item` has only one object all the time!

Answer (score 1):

I would build this atop some generic helper functions.

```js
const mapObject = (fn) => (obj) =>
  Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => [k, fn (v)]))

const group = (prop) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, {[prop]: p, ...rest}) => ({
    ... a, 
    [p] : [...(a[p] || []), rest]
  }), {})

const groupByYearAndMonth = (input) =>
  mapObject (group ('month')) (group ('year') (input))

const input = [
  {foo: 333, year: 2019, month: 'November', day: 29},
  {foo: 334, year: 2019, month: 'November', day: 30},
  {foo: 335, year: 2019, month: 'December', day: 1},
  {foo: 336, year: 2019, month: 'December', day: 2},
  // ...
  {foo: 362, year: 2019, month: 'December', day: 28},
  {foo: 363, year: 2019, month: 'December', day: 29},
  // ...
  {foo: 368, year: 2020, month: 'January', day: 3},
  {foo: 369, year: 2020, month: 'January', day: 4},
  // ...
  {foo: 396, year: 2020, month: 'February', day: 1},
  {foo: 397, year: 2020, month: 'February', day: 2},
  {foo: 398, year: 2020, month: 'February', day: 3},
  // ...
  {foo: 425, year: 2020, month: 'March', day: 30},
  {foo: 426, year: 2020, month: 'March', day: 31},
  // ...
]

console .log (groupByYearAndMonth (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here we have `group`, which takes a property name and returns a function which will group an array of objects into subarrays that have the same value for that property.  So, for instance,

```js
group ('a') ([{a: 'x', b: 1}, {a: 'x', b: 2}, {a: 'y', b: 3}, {a: 'x', b: 4}])
```

will yield

```js
{x: [{b: 1}, {b: 2}, {b: 4}], y: [{b: 3}]}
```

(Note that this removes the grouping parameter from the elements; there are times that's not wanted, but I think it's usually the correct behavior.)

And we have `mapObject`, which acts similarly to `Array.prototype.map` but operates on objects.  For instance,

```js
mapObject (n => n * n) ({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
```

returns

```js
{a: 1, b: 4, c: 9}
```

Combining these, we write `groupByYearAndMonth` by grouping the input by the year, and then using `mapObject`, grouping each year's array by the month.

Calling this on our input data, we get a result like this:

```js
{
  2019: {
    November: [
      // ...
      {foo: 333, day: 29},
      {foo: 334, day: 30}
    ],
    December: [
      {foo: 335, day: 1},
      {foo: 336, day: 2},
      // ...
      {foo: 362, day: 28},
      {foo: 363, day: 29}
    ]
  },
  2020: {
    January: [
      // ...
      {foo: 368, day: 3},
      {foo: 369, day: 4}
    ],
    February: [
      // ...
      {foo: 396, day: 1},
      {foo: 397, day: 2},
      {foo: 398, day: 3}
    ],
    March: [
      // ...
      {foo: 425, day: 30},
      {foo: 426, day: 31}
      // ...
    ]
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```